# await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync hangs during custom authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms

Within a "Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)" + .NET Standard + MobileAppService solution, I'm trying to use the code from http://blog.isharepoint.co.uk/?p=83.  The `await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` method call hangs indefinitely.  I call the Auth controller using Postman and can confirm the email and password are received and decoded okay.  Once the hang occurs, I cannot debug to find the error.  Before adding the custom authentication code, the project worked okay.  Lastly, I get the same behavior both on the local system and the Azure web server.

Here is the AuthController.cs file (see the IsPasswordValid method):

```
namespace MyAzure.MobileAppService.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private string signingKey, audience, issuer;

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _signInManager = value;
            }
        }

        public AuthController()
        { }

        public AuthController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            SignInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject assertion)
        {
            bool passValid = IsPasswordValid(assertion).Result;

            if (passValid)
            {
                if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY") == null)
                {
                    signingKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"];
                    audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"];
                    issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"];
                }
                else
                {
                    signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
                    var azureAppServiceEndpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
                    audience = $"https://{azureAppServiceEndpoint}/";
                    issuer = $"https://{azureAppServiceEndpoint}/";
                }

                string username = assertion.GetValue("email").Value<string>();

                JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(new Claim[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username) },
                    signingKey,
                    audience,
                    issuer,
                    TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

                return Ok(new LoginResult()
                {
                    AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
                    User = new LoginResultUser() { UserId = username }
                });
            }
            else // user assertion was not valid
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Wrong credentials");
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> IsPasswordValid(JObject assertion)
        {
            // this is where we would do checks agains a database
            try
            {
                string username = assertion.GetValue("email").ToString();
                string password = assertion.GetValue("password").ToString();

                var signInStatus = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, shouldLockout: true);
                
                switch (signInStatus)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:
                        return true;
                    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                        return false;
                    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                        return false;
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        return false;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using MyAzure.MobileAppService.DataObjects;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables;
    using System.Linq;
    
    namespace MyAzure.MobileAppService.Models
    {
        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";
    
            public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base(connectionStringName, throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {
                Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                    new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                        "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
            }
    
            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }
        }
    }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyAzure.MobileAppService.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
}
```

The last entries I see in the Debug console output are:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131689041142085279): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131689041142085279): Loaded
> 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-MyAzure.MobileAppService'.

It's very odd that System.Data.OracleClient is mentioned in the log.  I cannot find any place in my project that it is referenced.

Comment: Mixing async and blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()` can cause deadlocks.ie `IsPasswordValid(assertion).Result;`. Make that action async and then await the necessary method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing async and blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()` can cause deadlocks.

ie

```
...IsPasswordValid(assertion).Result;
```

Make that controller action *async* and then *await* the necessary method calls.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] JObject assertion) {
    bool passValid = await IsPasswordValid(assertion);

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Nice catch @Nkosi.  That was it.